# How to replace png icon with font-awesome icon?

Tags: icons, font-awesome, footer

I'd like to replace the "PNG" icons in the code below with "font-awesome"? Can someone help, making the replacement for me?

```
<!-- share buttons -->
<a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/YFXWd8p.png' title='Facebook'/></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/GyqTR6Z.png' title='Twitter'/></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/m6DKSKK.png' title='G+'/></a>
```

Comment: <!-- share buttons -->

Comment: Add in <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> and then reference the required then add the requried class for the button such as <i class="far fa-fireplace"></i> but amend this to a button. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to include icon for links.

Wrap the icon element inside the anchor tag and provide the link details to the a tag.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>fa fa-address-book</h1>

<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/"><i class="fa fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>


</body>
</html>
```

This will be your code

```
 <a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
```

Comment: <a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/YFXWd8p.png' title='Facebook'/></a>

Comment: Create a tag as you have done before and include the <i> tag with the corresponding class for the icon from font awsome css

Comment: <a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include Font Awesome to your page by placing it inside your `head` tag of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<!-- Include Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
```

To get an icon from Font Awesome, simply search on their [page](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) and include their HTML, e. g:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
```

Comment: <a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><img src='<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>' title='Facebook'/></a> ????

Comment: @mawga_bwoy No, replace `<img src='http://i.imgur.com/YFXWd8p.png' title='Facebook'/>` with `<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>`.

Comment: tank you alot! i got you!!

Comment: sorry, it don't working on my post footer, i can see just squares!! check it:

 <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'>
<!-- share buttons -->
<a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>

<a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>

Comment: @mawga_bwoy Your code seems right. Did you add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">`  in the `head` of your page?

Comment: @mawga_bwoy Glad to help :).